# Create dynamic spinner in android

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have to create a form in Android which may contain spinner or may not, based on data we have to create spinner. So I am trying to create a dynamic spinner in the form.
But it is not working. I am able to create the spinner but when I click on the spinner it show error message.

Code that I wrote:

```
dynamicSpinner = new Spinner(getApplicationContext());
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, option);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
dynamicSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

option is a `ArrayList<String>`, which content the list of the options.

If anyone have solution please share with me.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Spinner s=new Spinner(yourActivity.this);
ParentLayout.addView(s);
```

I dont see you adding your spinner to parent layout.
I am more interested in what error are you getting exactly

Answer (score 0):

Include a spinner in your xml with an id..

and then in code , use:

```
dynamicSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.mydynamicspinner);
```

instead of

```
dynamicSpinner = new Spinner(getApplicationContext());
```

rest all looks fine...

Comment: thanks Rahul... in my case I can't add spinner in the xml file. so I am trying to create the spinner dynamically. I mean using code..

Answer (score 0):

Have a `spinner` in your **`xml`**, then in `activity`, use following:

```
dynamicSpinner = (Spinner)findViewbyID(spinner ID);

if(data available)
    populate the spinner;
else
    dynamicSpinner.setVisibility(View.Gone);
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT :**
Incase you want to add `spinner` progarammatically, still you would be having a layout in `xml` which you are using in `setContentView(layout id)`.. so get the layout in which all the childs are present in `xml` throught its id and then add `spinner` to that layout.

Comment: thanks Farhan.. I want to create the spinner without using the xml file. I am trying to create using code...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried viewflipper?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

Its effective especially for those in need in multiple views/widgets.

The thing is just that, the widgets/views that will be viewed/added is defined in xml.

Hope it helps :D